# Rendered image only black and white noise

Tags: rendering

I am new to Blender and try to reproduce a YouTube Tutorial[Blender Tutorial: Splash Effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2dJbcTD6j0). Everything works fine, up until I try to render the image. What I get then is nothing but black and white noise, also known as salt-and-pepper noise:

[image: salt-and-pepper image]

I re-checked that the three light sources are set to Emission. The number of render samples is set to 10, but also increasing it to 100 doesn't change anything.

[Here is the blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nrxzavdes6kffwb/pepper-water-tutorial.blend?dl=0)

I'm sure I made a stupid noob mistake, but which?
Thanks a lot,
Polis

Comment: The best way to get help is by posting your blend file.

Comment: I'm surprised that people can't answer that question right away as it appears to be quite a noob problem. Anyway, I added a link to the blend file now. I hope you can open it.

Comment: You have two fluid domain objects. Try deleting one of them.

Comment: I just deleted the outer fluid domain object and now everything seems to work. However, I don't understand it as I think I did what was explained in the video, and it works there, and also the simulation worked fine. But thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you have two fluid domain objects, one of which has no material (`Cube`).

Since you can only have one fluid domain while baking, presumably this second domain got accidentally created after the bake was done. Since it has no material it defaults to diffuse. At 10 samples this diffuse surface appears pretty noisy, giving the result in your example render:

[image]

Delete it, and all is well:

[image]